# Traefik Ingress: Is blacklisting possible?

Tags: kubernetes, blacklist, traefik-ingress

Whitelisting ips is possible with this annotation: `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"`

Is it possible to do **the same with blacklisting?** would be nice to block some suspicous requests.

Comment: Unless those IPs are fixed, you really wouldn't want to have to edit the Ingress object every time just to block IPs. That said, [the configuration snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) is the way one can inject arbitrary nginx config blocks into a location, allowing you to do whatever you wish. It also seems modern nginx ingress controllers [support an opensource WAF](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/third-party-addons/modsecurity/) which may help, too

Comment: I have a traefik ingress in my cluster, so nginx options don't help

Comment: Oh, I see the line in your question where you didn't write that down -- my mistake for not breaking into your cluster to guess that. Good luck with your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately support for blocking ip addresses is not supported natively by traefik and any requests were [declined](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/4454) with a comment:

> We want to keep the IP filtering section as simple as possible and we
> think that your use case could be addressed differently.
>
> We think that a blacklisting task can be better achieved using a
> firewall.
>
> So, for now, and I insist on the "for now", we will decline your pull
> request.

For the same reason [#7926](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/7926) was declined.

You may be interested though in the those two plugins:

- https://pilot.traefik.io/plugins/276812076107694611/deny-ip-plugin
- https://pilot.traefik.io/plugins/280093067746214409/fail2-ban

Comment: Can I use those plugins with the traefik installed in k3s?